# APPCRASH 1CV8C.exe ошибка на WTF.DLL C0000005

Tags: 1с, pdf, adobe

При попытке открыть PDF внутри 1С (HTMLПоле) при подключении 1С через RemoteApp или локально на платформе 8.3.14, выдает ошибку APPCRASH со ссылкой на WTF.DLL С0000005. 
При запуске на платформе 8.3.15 выдает ошибку что не может найти Adobe Reader, при нажатии OK - открывает PDF корректно. 
Но проблема что "боевая" платформа все таки 8.3.14

---

Пока предположение что проблема в разнице разрядности ПО 1С (х64) а адоб ридер (x32). Под 32 разрядной платформой 1С 8.3.14. Разрядность для 1С - принципиальна

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла просто чистка реестра ccleaner-ом